# How to get 2 or more LinearRegionItem to overlap each other

Tags: python, pyqtgraph

I have added 2 `LinearRegionItems` to a `pyqtgraph` plot. When I move the boundary of 1 over the other, the boundary never overlaps the other.

I would like to know how to allow overlapping. This is a functionality that I need, where I am selecting different regions of the data plot to be used later on.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there was a bug in my code which was handling the case where a part of one LinearRegionItem overlapped with another LinearRegionItem.

Now I see that one linearRegionItem can lie on top of another one.

Consider this solved